# angular.js ngRoute Module is not refreshing the views

Tags: angularjs

i really need help with ngRoute module because whatever i do - partials in  are not getting updated.
Basically this is my folder structure:

https://gyazo.com/a5c7ce7e52687f525d8d1ffd718c9a5a

Index.html menu:

---

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/"><img src="images/logo.png" height=30 width=41></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#/">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"
                          aria-hidden="true"></span> Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/aboutus">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"
                          aria-hidden="true"></span> About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/menu">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"
                           aria-hidden="true"></span>
                Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/contactus">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

These are index.html includes:

```
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js">                            </script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services.js"></script>
```

These are the contents of app.js where i configure the routeProvider

---

```
'use strict';

angular.module('confusionApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
              $routeProvider
            // route for the contactus page
            .when('/contactus', {
                templateUrl : 'contactus.html',
                controller  : 'ContactController'
            })
        // route for the menu page
        .when('/menu', {
            templateUrl : 'menu.html',
            controller  : 'MenuController'
        })
        // route for the dish details page
        .when('/menu/:id', {
            templateUrl : 'dishdetail.html',
            controller  : 'DishDetailController'
        })
        .otherwise('/contactus');
}]);
```

---

I am using

```
<ng-view></ng-view>
```

to desplay partials, but nothing seems to do the work.
I am new to Angular, so any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!!!

Just in case there is controllers.js
    'use strict';

```
angular.module('confusionApp', [])

.controller('MenuController', ['$scope', 'menuFactory', function($scope, menuFactory) {

    $scope.tab = 1;
    $scope.filtText = '';
    $scope.showDetails = false;

    $scope.dishes= menuFactory.getDishes();

    $scope.select = function(setTab) {
        $scope.tab = setTab;

        if (setTab === 2) {
            $scope.filtText = "appetizer";
        }
        else if (setTab === 3) {
            $scope.filtText = "mains";
        }
        else if (setTab === 4) {
            $scope.filtText = "dessert";
        }
        else {
            $scope.filtText = "";
        }
    };

    $scope.isSelected = function (checkTab) {
        return ($scope.tab === checkTab);
    };

    $scope.toggleDetails = function() {
        $scope.showDetails = !$scope.showDetails;
    };
}])

.controller('ContactController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.feedback = {mychannel:"", firstName:"", lastName:"", agree:false, email:"" };

    var channels = [{value:"tel", label:"Tel."}, {value:"Email",label:"Email"}];

    $scope.channels = channels;
    $scope.invalidChannelSelection = false;

}])

.controller('FeedbackController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.sendFeedback = function() {

        console.log($scope.feedback);

        if ($scope.feedback.agree && ($scope.feedback.mychannel == "")) {
            $scope.invalidChannelSelection = true;
            console.log('incorrect');
        }
        else {
            $scope.invalidChannelSelection = false;
            $scope.feedback = {mychannel:"", firstName:"", lastName:"", agree:false, email:"" };
            $scope.feedback.mychannel="";
            $scope.feedbackForm.$setPristine();
            console.log($scope.feedback);
        }
    };
}])

.controller('DishDetailController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'menuFactory', function($scope, $routeParams, menuFactory) {

    var dish= menuFactory.getDish(parseInt($routeParams.id,10));
    $scope.dish = dish;
}])

.controller('DishCommentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    //Step 1: Create a JavaScript object to hold the comment from the form
    $scope.customer_comments = {author:"", rating:"", comment:"", date:""};
    $scope.customer_comments.rating = 5;

    $scope.submitComment = function () {



        //Step 2: This is how you record the date
        //"The date property of your JavaScript object holding the comment" = new Date().toISOString();
        var date = new Date().toISOString();
        $scope.customer_comments.date = date;
        console.log($scope.customer_comments);
        // Step 3: Push your comment into the dish's comment array
        //$scope.dish.comments.push("Your JavaScript Object holding the comment");
        $scope.customer_comments.rating = Number($scope.customer_comments.rating);
        $scope.dish.comments.push($scope.customer_comments);


        //Step 4: reset your form to pristine
        $scope.customer_comments = {name:"", number_of_stars:"", comment:"", date:""};
        $scope.commentForm.$setPristine();
        $scope.customer_comments.rating = 5;
        console.log($scope.customer_comments);


        //Step 5: reset your JavaScript object that holds your comment
    }
}])
```

;

Comment: this is a link to app.js

Comment: can you show the code of your controller

Comment: Thank you, just added it to the request!

Answer (score 0):

Seems your app.js is in wrong folder. Keep it outside the scripts folder i.e. parallel to html pages.

Hope this works!!

Comment: r u seeing any errors on console? If yes, please share those

Comment: the partial a ok https://gyazo.com/071fdda8620218247fedbb3c85d0740a and there are no errors https://gyazo.com/9f37a4e9425cf32961fffc7d1a3a768b

Comment: For a last thing to do.. jus try something like this.

Comment: Vamshi, what should i try?

Comment: I guess the issue here is you are creating module in app.js, controller.js and probably in service.js also. Instead of that create module only once in app.js. And use that variable everywhere i.e in controller.js and service.js.

Comment: Ex:  var confusionApp = module('confusionApp', ['ngRoute']); and use "confusionApp" variable in other places wherever needed!

Comment: No mate, still the same.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing **ng-app="confusionApp"** in you html code

Comment: Buddy, it is there <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">

Answer (score 0):

We should never initialize angualr.module() in each place as it going to replace the previous module and create a new one.

Here as you are creating module in app.js, controller.js (and probably in service.js also), you are unable to achieve the required functionality.

> Instead of that create module only once in app.js. And use that variable everywhere i.e in controller.js and service.js
>
> Ex: var confusionApp = module('confusionApp', ['ngRoute']); and use "confusionApp" variable in other places wherever needed!

Hopefully this should work!!

Comment: Done, nothing changed.

Comment: Did u changed the structure as I told u or is it the same still? app.js parallel to htmls. While routing u have given the path in such a way, that's why I am stressing on it

Comment: hello buddy. Cought it. so: app.js - angular.module('confusionApp', ['ngRoute']) / services.js - angular.module('confusionApp') and controers.js angular.module('confusionApp', []) and the controler.js should be angular.module('confusionApp') !

Comment: You prblm is solved or still persists? can you plz share the modified code?

Comment: Deear Vashmi. I am very thankful for your fast response and great help! I found out the mistake i made. In my controllers.js I should not have included '[]' so it wouldnt create a new moule but look for existing one. So: app.js - angular.module('confusionApp', ['ngRoute']),  services.js - angular.module('confusionApp') and controers.js angular.module('confusionApp', []) and the controler.js should be angular.module('confusionApp') ! That way we create the module in app.js and use it afterwards on both services and controllers. Thank you, Vamshi!!!

Answer (score 0):

I am very thankful for fast response and great help! I found out the mistake i made. In my controllers.js I should not have included '[]' so it wouldnt create a new moule but look for existing one. So: app.js - angular.module('confusionApp', ['ngRoute']), services.js - angular.module('confusionApp') and controers.js angular.module('confusionApp', []) and the controler.js should be angular.module('confusionApp') ! That way we create the module in app.js and use it afterwards on both services and controllers. Thank you all